# ansible command not found

Tags: python, ansible

I have installed ansible on mac osx using the following:

```
pip3 install ansible==2.9.15 netaddr jmespath
```

After installation, I am able to run and ansible command (e.g. `ansible --version`, `ansible --help`, etc) from the command line from any location.  Then I run a process that autobuilds some Virtualbox VMs.  The VMs get created then when the process goes to call ansible to apply playbooks, I get an error stating that ansible cannot be found.

Now I can no longer run ansible commands from the command line unless I run it in the following ways:

1. `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.10_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ansible`
2. from that directory `./ansible`

I can no longer just run ansible from anywhere.  My $PATH has the correct path specified as follows:

```
/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

I have also rebooted my machine as well.

whenever I try to run ansible the way I did before, from anywhere, I get the following:

```
zsh: command not found: ansible
```

Any suggestions on how to get back the ability to run ansible as one would expect, from anywhere on the system?

Thanks!

Comment: did you install ansible in a virtualenv ? OR running a different virtualenv  now?

Comment: nope, installed ansible directly on my mac osx OS.  VirtualBox is also installed on my mac.  the custom process i then run creates several VirtualBox VMs then is supposed to use Ansible to apply some playbooks.  It is this step that is failing and confirmed by my direct inability to call Ansible any longer from the command line, unless I do one of the two methods mentioned in the original post...

Answer (score 3):

I had multiple ansible instances . I followed the steps below and rectified the ansible command not found error.

1. Uninstall old /all instances of ansible

```
python3 -m pip uninstall ansible
python3 -m pip uninstall ansible-core
```

2. Find all instances of ansible

```
cd ~
find . | grep ansible
```

3. Remove all directories from step 2

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible*
rm -rf /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
rm -rf ./.ansible
rm -rf ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_test
```

4. Install ansible once again

```
sudo yum install python3-pip 
pip3 install ansible
pip3 install openshift
```

5. Validate

```
pip3 list  | grep ansible
ansible (4.8.0)
ansible-core (2.11.6)
```

```
ansible --version
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.8 (default, Sep 12 2021, 04:40:35) [GCC 
8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)]. This feature will be removed from ansible-core in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False 
in ansible.cfg.
ansible [core 2.11.6] 
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Sep 12 2021, 04:40:35) [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

[ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible)

Comment: Removing in site-packages things is matter I think.